# CSIDL_SYSTEMX86 and CSIDL_SYSTEM (C++)

Tags: visual-c++

When trying to return the path to system32 so I can launch notepad from an application I am developing, I do the following:

```
if (SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
        GetSafeHwnd(),
        lSystemPath,
        CSIDL_SYSTEM,
        TRUE ) )
    {
        lSystemPathCString = lSystemPath;
        if (lSystemPathCString.ReverseFind('\\') != lSystemPathCString.GetLength() - 1)
            lSystemPathCString += "\\";
    }
```

However.... in `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()`, using `CSIDL_SYSTEM` ends up setting `lSystemPath` to C:\Windows\system32, whereas using `CIDSL_SYSTEMX86` sets `lSystemPath` to C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Is this the correct behavior? It seems like those identifiers are switched, and I want to make sure that this is not merely strange behavior on my system.

Thanks in advance for any help in clearing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64` contains 32-bit binaries (even though it has `64` in its name): this is correct behaviour.

[WOW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) stands for *Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I only questioned it because in C#, Environment.GetFolderPath() returns either system32 or syswow64 based on which identifier you give it, so I was expecting the same behavior.

Comment: @AlexanderMiles: it is unfortunate that the .NET convention is different from the Windows convention. But there's some justification: a single .NET executable can run in multiple environments, so it's more useful for "special folder" values to map automatically to the best folder. A native executable must be recompiled per environment, and in addition there are times when a x64 program needs to access x86 locations, so forcing the program to be explicit is somewhat more appropriate there. Note that CSIDL_SYSTEMX86 does get you the expected system32 dir for x86 exe on x86 OS.